# What does it mean "Initials of First Name(s)" in registration context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I see a request to fill the "**Initials of First Name(s)**" on registration, what does it mean? Does it mean that I have to put the first letter of my first name or it means something else?

[image]

Comment: I've not seen that in a web form before.  Is it targeting a certain population of English-speakers where people are apt to go by a set of first initials?Some parts of India, perhaps?

Comment: It's Netherlands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *initial* is the first letter of a given name, therefore yes, you are correct in your assumption that you have to put the first letter of your first name.

The reason that the form allows for a possible plural in *Name(s)* is that in many cultures, people can have more than one first name (the actress [Sarah Michelle Gellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Michelle_Gellar) for example), therefore the person may choose to use more than one initial.

Comment: Thank you. I have to add that in case of *one* name the computer can do that by itself, therefore it's apparently weird to request it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Put in the first letter of your first name. I would guess that the plural is so that, should you have multiple first names, you can put both initials in (e.g. "Mary Jane" -> "MJ", although I would expect people to just use M).